# Facebook Unity Sdk v5.0.3 crashes in Landscape mode when trying to login - Android

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

The game crashes when I click at login button as the game is in landscape mode. If I use portrait mode, everything works fine and correctly.

I got the following stack trace from bugsense when I got the crash.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.adssdk.plugins/com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.
1at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2205)
2at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
3at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3809)
4at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
5at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1266)
6at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
7at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
8at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
9at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
13at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
14Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Session: an attempt was made to request new permissions for a session that has a pending request.
15at com.facebook.Session.requestNewPermissions(Session.java:1006)
16at com.facebook.Session.requestNewPublishPermissions(Session.java:512)
17at com.facebook.unity.FB.initAndLogin(FB.java:200)
18at com.facebook.unity.FB.LoginUsingActivity(FB.java:249)
19at com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity.onCreate(FBUnityLoginActivity.java:13)
20at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4538)
21at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1071)
22at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2161)
```

If anyone of you has implemented this in landscape mode and is not getting a crash while logging in, do let me know.

Answer (score 4):

yes, this is a bug, we are working on proper fix right now.
Meanwhile you can edit your android manifest in Plugins/Android and add *android:configChanges* so that *FBUnityLoginActivity* isn't destroyed when orientation/whatever changes:

```
<activity 
  android:name="com.facebook.unity.FBUnityLoginActivity" 
  android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen"
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
</activity>
```

you may also want to remove "Translucent" from activity style.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to implement this one.

Also I'm facing an issue with the incorrect keyhash generation..  
I'm having a abc.keystore with alias named 'al1', and I generated the keyhash with keytool in cmd(windows). On running the app i get an exception.. API Keytool Exception : incoorect keyhash doesn'y match in the stored entries (something like this). SO, I make a new alias 'al2' and sign my application with it.. And guess what i works fine with facebook and I'm able to login.

Comment: My application has been signed with key 'al1'(fb login not working) and is live on the play store. Is there any way to fix this? Let me know as this is very urgent. I can't even remove it from the play store because it is becoming popular. So what to do? Any ideas?

Comment: You just need to add keyhash of that application(signed with 'al1') to Facebook developer dashboard. One you can see in Unity editor is just "debug" keyhash. Easiest way would be to create a build signed with 'al1' and run it on test device. Let the login fail and check logcat for error looking like _com.facebook.http.protocol.ApiException: Key hash yQiO9KqD3fSZRhARTQ5BkPNpLoc does not match any stored key hashes._ that is the keyhash you should add to Facebook dev dashboard

Comment: Fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks, @juraj for providing the fix, I had this issue today with the SDK 5.1
But I really wonder why there is no fix yet or at least the manifest that is generated by the SDK is adjusted the way you posted it. I searched for this issue about one day and of course I'm really annoyed right now :/ There are a lot of apps, especially games, which are only run in landscape mode, so please give them at least a hint what goes wrong! I used logcat and it didn't even give me the "Unable to start activity" log. The only feedback I got was OnLoginComplete callback with "cancelled":true

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that the change in the manifest file fixed the crash for me also. As additional info: the location of manifest the file was in Assets\Plugins\Android and the name was AndroidManifest.xml. I tested the fix on Sony Xperia M.