# Facebook SDK 5.0.4 for Unity, Android, Login Fails, Correct Hash Key

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I think I have the same problem as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22238125/facebook-login-fails-with-fb-app-installed) post.

I am using `Unity4.3.0f4` and `Facebook SDK 5.0.4 beta`.

I use the correct key hash (not the debug one) which I obtained by `FB.Android.KeyHash`. On my own device, as well as on BlueStacks emulator, I manage to log in and `FB.Feed` normally. However, other users that have tested the app cannot login. `FB.Login("publish_actions", callback)` is called, the permission dialog is shown, the user taps OK and then returns to game. `Result.text` is then

```
{"is_logged_in":false, "user_id":"", "access_token":"", "access_token_expires_at":"01/01/0001 00:00:00"}
```

Any idea?

- ps. On my phone i have an earlier version of the Facebook app, not the last one.
- ps2. You can [download](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=gr.ntua.ece.babis.fingerswifts) my app and [take part](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/108633474582242230089) in the beta testing to see the problem yourself.

Comment: There are answers in the other post that you linked.  Did they help you out at all?

Comment: @BrianJew The answer wasn't there when I created the question. I added the new hash key to the Facebook App Dashboard. I will have the users test it and let you know. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @BrianJew it didn't fix the problem... I don't think it is a key hash error. As I mentioned above, I use the correct key hash, from the keystore with which I sign my application, **not** the debug one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after all the problem was that I was trying to log in while immediately requesting the `publish_actions` permission, which by the way is NOT needed for `FB.Feed()`.

```
FB.Login ("publish_actions", AuthCallback); // WRONG!!!!!!
```

Finally I used

```
FB.Login ("", AuthCallback); // Ok
```

and it works properly at last.

Comment: you should be able to request "publish_actions" without any problem.. what you may have experienced is orientation bug described here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21368820/3179004

Comment: @juraj it was not the orientation bug: I had already modified the manifest according to the answer you 've indicated. Also, when I changed `FB.Login ("publish_actions", AuthCallback)` to `FB.Login ("", AuthCallback)` (_and this was the **only** difference between the two beta versions of the app_) it started working properly for everyone. Do you have an explanation for this other than mine?
Please do not downvote if you are not sure that this actually solved my problem.

Comment: No worries, I haven't downvoted you(don't even have enough rep) + I upvoted you right now! It is a bug, requiring only "publish_actions" doesn't work, your solution or requiring "email,publish_actions" works just fine. We will take a at it. Thanks for your report!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your test users can see the app.

My guess in your app is sandboxed and your test users are not listed on Developer Dashboard.

Either un-sandbox it, or add them as Testers(its in Roles tab)

Comment: The app is not in sandboxed mode... At the Developer Dashboard, I go to `Status & Review` and the button `Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?` is turned ON (`YES`). Also there is a green circle next to the app name.